# wxpython media.mediactrl.load question

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

ok so im using LoadFromURI to load an mp3 file, the script works fine on one of my laptops running win64 but when i use it on the other laptop win32 it takes a while to load the song !, what does the command actually do ?i used LoadFromURI, Load, LoadURI and got the same results, when i use Load for example is the file being downloaded somewhere in the harddrive ? or is it simply being streamed over the server ?

im new to this so i could be missing something obvious

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that streams the file, it doesn't actually download it. Someone wrapped the cross-platform media player, mplayer for wxPython. I think it's more robust than the included MediaCtrl. Here's one article on it: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/ and here's the download and docs page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MplayerCtrl/